# Correctly indent javascript inside script tags on VIM

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation

I need help getting VIM to correctly indent javascript inside script tags.

This is what I want it to look like:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-257015-24']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
  </script>
```

This is what it looks like when I let VIM indent, which is quite nice, but not optimal:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-257015-24']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
  </script>
```

My VIM files are roughly these ones: http://github.com/lunks/vimfiles

I have tried appending script to the tags I want to indent on my `vimrc`:

```
let g:html_indent_inctags = "body,head,tbody,ul,li,p,script"
```

But then, although it successfully indents the content following the `script` tag, it doesn't indent its contents as javascript anymore, rather it's just text.

How can I make VIM indent Javascript inside script tags the way I intend to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one did it: https://github.com/vim-scripts/indenthtml.vim

Make sure to add to your vimrc:

```
let g:html_indent_script1 = "inc"
let g:html_indent_style1 = "inc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `:set ft=html.javascript` or search for a better indent file for HTML/JS on vim.org.